# UIbutton on UITableview Section View doesn't animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cabasicanimation

i am working on a tableview which contains main categories and sub categories. Basically main categories are tableview section headers and when user clicks on a button in  tableview section header, i set my tableview to show these subcategories (rows) in the tableview.

Everything works great but what i want to do is when a user clicks on the "show subcategories button" in section header, i want that button to animate and rotate 90 degrees. The button is a UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure type so i guess u got what i want.

The animation works when i add the animation code to my "viewForHeaderInSection" delegate method, but it doesnt work from the outside. strangely the click actions are also working. Heres the code (Just to make things clear, the user can also just click on a main category to show everything in that category with the gesture recognizer):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

MainCategory* cat = [self.tableViewArray objectAtIndex:section];

UIView* view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 0, 300, 44)];
UIView* imageView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 40, 40)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
label.text = cat.name;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[view addSubview:label];
[view addSubview:imageView];
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectMainCategory:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
view.tag = section;
if([cat.subcategories count]>0){
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 44, 44);
    button.tag = section;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(subCategoryClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:button];
}
return view;
}
```

And for my Button Click Action:

```
- (IBAction)subCategoryClick:(UIButton*)sender{

    NSLog(@"click!");
    MainCategory* cat = [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSNumber* section = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];
    if(![openSections containsObject:section]){
        [openSections addObject:section];


        NSMutableArray* indexPathsToAdd = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 0;i<[cat.subcategories count];i++){
            [indexPathsToAdd addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sender.tag]];
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToAdd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [self rotateButton:sender isOpeningSection:YES];

    }else{
        [openSections removeObject:section];

        NSMutableArray* indexPathsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 0;i<[cat.subcategories count];i++){
            [indexPathsToRemove addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sender.tag]];
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        [self rotateButton:sender isOpeningSection:NO];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And at last, my animation method (just to see if it is animating, not the final method):

```
- (void)rotateButton:(UIButton*)button isOpeningSection:(BOOL)isOpen{
    CABasicAnimation *halfTurn;
    halfTurn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    halfTurn.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    halfTurn.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    halfTurn.duration = 0.5;
    halfTurn.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [[button layer] addAnimation:halfTurn forKey:@"180"];
}
```

as i said, when i add the rotatebutton contents to the viewForSection method, the button is rotating but it doesnt rotates when called from the lick event. I guess i am targeting the wrong button layer in this method..

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the call to `reloadData` is forcing the table view to create a new view from `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`, which immediately removes the old one from the view hierarchy and adds the unrotated one back.

Possible solutions:

- If you are already doing animation in `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` or `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, do you need the call to `reloadData` at all?  It most likely is ruining those animations in addition to your rotation animation.
- You could create your section headers ahead of time (in `viewDidLoad` perhaps) and just return the reference in  `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.  This would keep any animations intact when you call `reloadData`.

Comment: didnt know hat i didnt need to reload data when i was using insertrows or deleterows. i was wondering why my animations were acting strange lol thanks

Answer (score 1):

360*PI/180 = 2PI. Thats 360 degree. Use M_PI/2.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the rotation degree is there for just testing, the main problem is the animation doesn't apply to the button when the "rotatebutton" method is called.

Comment: Hmm Is it because you call reloadData in click method? This will call the viewForHeader where you make a new button! The animation happens in the old one